# What is the correct client side implementation of consuming HAL API Endpoint that returns a list of links

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, hateoas, hal

Based on the [Richardson Maturity Model](https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) some API systems are implemented with `Level 3 - Hypermedia API architecture style` in mind. As i am concerned about it as it still an Internet Draft (a "work in progress"), I am dealing with one of those systems currently and I am working on creating a client side generic implementation to deal with it.

First things first, I have a basic scenario as the title of the question shown. I am using C#. Consuming a HAL API Endpoint that returns a json like the below and you can see inside `CarsApiHeaderModels` I have an array of objects that contains a link to each object so i can navigate through:

```
    {
    "proberty1": "value1",
    "proberty2": "value2",
    "CarsApiHeaderModels": [
        {
            "CarId": "e41b63e6-3678-4f79-92da-aabc00da06b3",
            "CarReference": "xxxxx",
            "_links": [
                {
                    "Rel": "getCar",
                    "Href": "api/CarApi/e41b63e6-3678-4f79-92da-aabc00da06b3",
                    "Title": null,
                    "IsTemplated": false
                },
                {
                    "Rel": "getCar",
                    "Href": "api/CarApi/7b05bde2-aa55-4400-9343-98ba3287ca03",
                    "Title": null,
                    "IsTemplated": false
                }
            ],
            "_embedded": null
        }
    ],
    "TotalCount": 2,
    "_links": [
        {
            "Rel": "self",
            "Href": "api/CarListApi?proberty1=value1&proberty2=value2",
            "Title": null,
            "IsTemplated": false
        }
    ],
    "_embedded": null
}
```

I wanted to retrieve a `List<Car>` not a list of links to the car resource's endpoints which have shown under `CarsApiHeaderModels` but because i am dealing with a HAL compliant API, that's what i am getting.

In the C# client side, what is the efficient way of getting a list of Car objects. Is the right way to iterate through each link and retrieve the object? To be honest that doesn't make sense to me? Also I've went through many discussions and implementations but it seems the topic not mature enough and has a lot of urging between the developers.

Comment: I've been working on a JS client for a few years: https://github.com/evert/ketting. This model seems to work really well for developers. I would go for a similar approach in C#. However, the JSON you posted is definitely not HAL. There's a ton of incompatibilities.

Comment: @Evert That's the exact JSON that i am getting. I will take a look on this library approach, Even if that JSON is incompatible with the hal specifications but looking into this github library will give me a clue about the correct consumption, so Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, this JSON looks somewhat HAL inspired.. but yea it's definitely something else.

Comment: @Evert After reading the specification, i did see that there is a feature of the HAL called Embedded resources and i can see in the returning json that i have _embedded but equal null. I think that's answer my question, if i can find out how to return the _embedded objects instead of just links to them. Is it a way from the client side to tell the endpoint to return the Embedded resources?

Comment: There's really no way of telling. HAL is just a specification for a document format, but it doesn't say anything about how the server should behave. It's completely up to the implementer. And given that they went with something so non-standard, all assumptions are out the window. Consult the documentation, source or developers of the api you are integrating with.